# How do you mock Auth0 MangementClient using jest?

Tags: jestjs, auth0

This is also a question on [Auth0 node-auth0 library](https://github.com/auth0/node-auth0/issues/299). The use case is that I am using the Auth0 [create Actions API](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Actions/post_action) through [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/alekc/auth0/latest/docs/resources/action) and want to be able to writes tests against the Actions.

In this example I want to be able to test the `onExecutePostLogin` without using real values.

```js
// auth0-post-login.js

exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
  const userId = event.user.user_id

  const ManagementClient = require('auth0').ManagementClient
  const management = new ManagementClient({
    domain: event.secrets.domain,
    clientId: event.secrets.clientId,
    clientSecret: event.secrets.clientSecret,
    audience: `https://${event.secrets.domain}/api/v2/`,
    scope: 'read:users',
  })

  const params = { id: userId, page: 0, per_page: 50, include_totals: false }
  let userPermissions = await management.getUserPermissions(params)
  const map = require('array-map')
  const permissions = map(userPermissions, function(permission) {
    return permission.permission_name
  })

  api.accessToken.setCustomClaim('https://example.com/access', permissions.join(' '))
}
```

One of the main issues is that the functions like `getUserPermissions` is created through their utility wrapper:

```js
utils.wrapPropertyMethod(ManagementClient, 'getUserPermissions', 'users.getPermissions');
```

This causes jest to have issues finding the functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did something similar as stsmurf to mock the response of the Auth0 methods.

I have a file where I store my helper methods like "find a role by its name"

```js
// helper.ts

import { ManagementClient } from 'auth0';

export const getRoleByName = async (roleName: string) => {
  const api = new ManagementClient({
    clientId: clientId,
    clientSecret: clientSecret,
    domain: domain,
  });

  const roles = await api.getRoles();
  const role = roles.find((r) => r.name == roleName);
  if (!role) throw new Error('Role not found');

  return role;
};
```

```js
// helper.test.ts

import { Role } from 'auth0';

import { getRoleByName } from './helpers';

const mockGetRoles = jest.fn();
jest.mock('auth0', () => {
  return {
    ManagementClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        getRoles: mockGetRoles,
      };
    }),
  };
});

describe('Get role', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    const dummyRoles: Role[] = [
      { id: 'fake_id_1', description: 'Fake role nr 1', name: 'Fake Role 1' },
      { id: 'fake_id_2', description: 'Fake role nr 2', name: 'Fake Role 2' },
    ];
    mockGetRoles.mockImplementation(() => dummyRoles);
  });

  it('can return a role if it exists', async () => {
    const expectedResult: Role = {
      id: 'fake_id_1',
      description: 'Fake role nr 1',
      name: 'Fake Role 1',
    };
    const result = await getRoleByName('Fake Role 1');

    expect(expectedResult).toEqual(result);
  });

  it('will throw an error when a role is not found', async () => {
    await expect(getRoleByName('Fake Role 3')).rejects.toThrowError();
  });
});
```

Comment: Somehow stsmurf's answer didn't work for me (it complained that 'ManagementClient is not a constructor') but your example did.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get to functions like `getUserPermissions` I needed to override the implementation of the `ManagementClient`. This allowed me to then define `getUserPermissions` as a mock function.

```js
import { onExecutePostLogin } from './auth0-post-login'

const mockManagementClient = jest.fn()
const mockGetUserPermissions = jest.fn()

jest.mock('auth0', () => {
  return {
    ManagementClient: (opts) => {
      mockManagementClient(opts)
      return {
        getUserPermissions: (params) => {
          return mockGetUserPermissions(params)
        },
      }
    },
  }
})

describe('onExecutePostLogin', () => {
  const mockSetCustomClaim = jest.fn()

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockSetCustomClaim.mockClear()
    mockManagementClient.mockClear()
    mockGetUserPermissions.mockClear()
    mockGetUserPermissions.mockReturnValue([
      {
        permission_name: 'read:foo',
      },
      {
        permission_name: 'update:bar',
      },
    ])
  })

  const event = {
    user: {
      user_id: 'abcd123',
    },
    secrets: {
      domain: 'test-example.us.auth0.com',
      clientId: 'a-client-id',
      clientSecret: 'a-client-secret',
    },
  }

  const api = {
    accessToken: {
      setCustomClaim: mockSetCustomClaim,
    },
  }

  it('initializes a ManagementClient', async () => {
    await onExecutePostLogin(event, api)

    expect(mockManagementClient).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      domain: event.secrets.domain,
      clientId: event.secrets.clientId,
      clientSecret: event.secrets.clientSecret,
      audience: `https://${event.secrets.domain}/api/v2/`,
      scope: 'read:users',
    })
  })

  it('gets users permissions', async () => {
    await onExecutePostLogin(event, api)

    expect(mockGetUserPermissions).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      { id: event.user.user_id, page: 0, per_page: 50, include_totals: false },
    )
  })

  it('sets custom claims', async () => {
    await onExecutePostLogin(event, api)

    const expectedPermissions = 'read:foo update:bar'
    expect(mockSetCustomClaim).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      'https://example.com/access', expectedPermissions,
    )
  })
})
```